# Tool to transform text to all caps or lowercase

Tags: macos, text

Is there a system-wide text manipulation app that enables you to select text and convert all letters to upper case or lower case, like a code text editor would?

Comment: An automator service could do this trick. It can be accessed from the contextual menu of the textboxes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set this up as a right click service in automator as @Matthieu Riegler suggested.

Open up Automator.app and create a “Service” with this workflow.

[image]

Pay close attention to the checkbox up top, “Output replaces selected test”.  After the workflow is in place and saved, navigate to “System Preferences-->Keyboard.”  On the left hand side select “Services”.  On the right hand side you will see the Service you created, in the example its saved as “UpperCase”.  Then give it a shortcut by pressing “Add Shortcut” and give it what you would like.  Tested in TestWrangler and TextEdit.

Script used in Automator:

```
on run {input, parameters}
set upperCaseString to ¬
    (do shell script ("echo " & input & " | tr a-z A-Z;"))
return upperCaseString
end run
```

Comment: That's enough for 'English' language, but you can also add diacritical translation, like so

set upperCaseString to ¬
  (do shell script ("echo " & input & " | tr a-zäáà A-ZÄÁÀ;"))  add an specials to your list like ä, ß and so on

Answer (score 5):

I am on Mountain Lion 10.8.5 and for all editable text I can select and right click the text and choose `Transformations -> Make Upper Case`.

[image]

However, it seems this does not work in all applications. TextWrangler for example does not show this menu. All system applications (Finder, TextEdit, Mail, Calendar, etc...) do.

Comment: This continues to work as of 2018, e.g. in High Sierra (10.13.x)

Answer (score 1):

Another tool that I use is [**PopClip**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/popclip/id445189367?mt=12)

The application can transform selected text to UPPERCASE or even Proper Case or lowercase.  There are several settings for search and other context relevant actions.

I am not affiliated with the developer.

[image: PopClip Settings]

[image: PopClip context]

This is a sample based editing this answer...

---

[image: PopClip in context using selected text]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle so I create a one button app that solves this problem. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the Lowly Mac App]

You'll find the [Lowly app](http://www.daniele.catalanotto.ch/lowly) here :)

Answer (score 0):

[WordService](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordservice/id899972312?mt=12) will solve your problem. It's a free app from [Devon Technologies](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html) that provides system-wide Services that do various text manipulations, including changing case.